# How to check whether SIM card is present in a J2ME device or not?

Tags: java-me

How can I check whether SIM card is present in a J2ME device or not.

Comment: Why a downvote for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `System.getProperty("microedition.smartcardslots");`, but it is dependent on `JSR 177` Security and Trust Services API for J2ME (SATSA).

Answer (score 1):

It is **possible** in some ways.

**Refer the following links:**

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?227658-How-to-check-wheather-a-SIM-card-has-been-inserted-in-mobile-using-j2me

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?105450-SIM-access-from-J2ME-%28deploy-SIM-application%29